# Constraints, how do I compare an attribute's value with another?

Tags: sql, ddl

This is a very beginner question, but my google skills have failed me and I can't seem to find anything in my notes.

In my assignment, I have to create several constraints based on criteria given by our professor.

We have a table called Employee. The employee's have a rank(char), and that rank can be 'DB Guru', 'DB expert', or 'DB rookie'. They also have a salary (integer). This constraint I was able to make easily.

The constraint that comes after is to make sure that anyone with the rank 'DB guru' has a salary above 200.

I'm confused as to how I check to see if the value for rank is 'DB guru' and also check to see if the salary is above 200. It's the code that checks the rank that I can't seem to find how to do.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
IC2: The salary of a 'DB guru' is above 200. 
*/ 
CONSTRAINT IC2 CHECK(rank IN('DB guru') AND  salary > 200)),
```

Which gives me the error:
ERROR at line 14:
ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Line 14 is the Cconstraint I posted, so I'm guessing this is a syntax error.

Could someone show me an example of proper syntax to compare these values?

Thank you for your help in advance.

EDIT: Here is the entire Create statement, as well as my attempts at each constraint.

```
-- IMPORTANT: use the names IC1, IC2, etc. as given below. 
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
DROP TABLE Employee CASCADE CONSTRAINTS; 
DROP TABLE Dependent CASCADE CONSTRAINTS; 
-- 
CREATE TABLE Employee 
( 
id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
name    CHAR(10)  NOT NULL,  
rank    CHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
salary  INTEGER NOT NULL, 
/* 
IC1: The rank is one of: 'DB guru', 'DB expert', or 'DB rookie' 
*/ 
COnstraing IC1 CHECK(rank IN('DB guru', 'DB expert', 'DB rookie')),

IC2: The salary of a 'DB guru' is above 200. 
*/ 
CONSTRAINT IC2 CHECK(rank IN('DB guru') AND salary > 200)),
/* 
IC3: The salary of a 'DB expert' is between 80 and 220 (inclusive). 
*/ 
CONSTRAINT IC3 CHECK(rank IN('DB expert) AND salary >= 80 AND salary <= 220),
/* 
IC4: The salary of a 'DB rookie' is less than 100. 
*/ 
CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK(rank IN('DB rookie') AND salary < 100))
);
```

Comment: +1 for actually trying to do your homework! :)

Comment: Haha no credit for no answers, right?

Comment: Could you post your entire create/alter statement? I suspect the ), at the end may be a syntax error.

Comment: @eaolson, posted. As far as I can tell, all the parentheses match up.

Comment: "rank" is a reserved word. Better not use it as a column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, again, what this check is saying:

```
CONSTRAINT IC2 CHECK(rank IN('DB guru') AND salary > 200))
```

This is saying that, for *every* row, `rank` must be exactly equal to `'DB Guru'`, and `salary` must be greater than 200. That's *not* what you want. You need to think about it the other way around - if the `rank` is anything *other* than `'DB Guru'`, then you don't care (in this constraint) what their salary is. So you actually want:

```
CONSTRAINT IC2 CHECK(rank != 'DB guru' OR salary > 200)
```

You also had an extra `)` at the end (count the `()`s in the first example, you'll find that they're not balanced). You have a similar error at the end of `IC4`.

---

Sidebar for @wildplasser - As I've said, our two `IC2`s are equivalent, using a little bit of boolean logic:

```
NOT( zrank IN('DB guru') AND salary <= 200) --Your IC2
```

equals:

```
(NOT zrank IN ('DB guru')) OR (NOT salary <= 200) --De Morgan's law
```

equals:

```
(zrank != 'DB guru') OR (NOT salary <= 200) --Simplification of first
```

equals:

```
(zrank != 'DB guru') OR (salary > 200) --Simplification of second
```

equals:

```
zrank != 'DB guru' OR salary > 200 --Removal of brackets, my IC2
```

Comment: Please note that the salary ranges for expert and guru overlap, so the plain OR does not work here.

Comment: The original IC3 has an upper limit of 220, which overlaps with the lower limit of IC2. Your implementation would prevent experts to have salaries in the {200,220} range.

Comment: @wilplasser - I haven't shown a corrected `IC3` in my answer, but it requires the same treatment I've shown for `IC2` - it would be `CHECK(rank!='DB Expert' OR salary between 80 and 220)`. `IC2` doesn't control the salary range for an expert, since `rank!='DB Guru'` is true, so `IC2` is met.

Comment: Note: You used the initial version of my answer (but changed the 220 to a 200). After your comment to my answer, I updated my answer. See the OR-list in IC3.

Comment: @wildplasser - Nope, still missing whatever point it is you're trying to make - I've shown above how our two `IC2` constraints are equivalent. And in a previous comment I've said how I would define `IC3` (and I can again demonstrate that what I've given is equivalent to the one in your answer)

Comment: Explaining what the check was saying was exactly what I was not understanding about the constraints. You also pointed out the errors in my syntax, and my question was directly related to syntax. Both your answer and @wildplasser 's helped immensely but I'm choosing yours for the reasons I listed. Thank you.

Comment: As per de Morgans laws they are equivalent. (good thing that zrank is not NULLable ...). And indeed, there were some minor syntactical problems with the OQ (commaas, parenthesis) And semantic: the usage of "rank" as a column name.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------- 
-- IMPORTANT: use the names IC1, IC2, etc. as given below. 
-- -------------------------------------------------------------------- 

DROP TABLE Employee CASCADE ;
-- 
CREATE DOMAIN dbarank AS CHAR(10) CHECK (VALUE IN ('DB guru', 'DB expert', 'DB rookie') );

CREATE TABLE Employee
( id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
, name    CHAR(10)  NOT NULL
, zrank    dbarank NOT NULL -- "rank" is a reserved name
, salary  INTEGER NOT NULL

-- IC2: The salary of a 'DB guru' is above 200. 
, CONSTRAINT IC2 CHECK ( NOT( zrank IN('DB guru') AND salary <= 200))

-- IC3: The salary of a 'DB expert' is between 80 and 220 (inclusive). 
, CONSTRAINT IC3 CHECK ( NOT (zrank IN ('DB expert') AND ( salary < 80 OR salary > 220)))
-- IC4: The salary of a 'DB rookie' is less than 100. 
, CONSTRAINT IC4 CHECK ( NOT (zrank IN('DB rookie') AND salary >= 100))
);
INSERT INTO Employee(id,name,zrank,salary) VALUES(1, 'Pipo', 'Clown', 1);
INSERT INTO Employee(id,name,zrank,salary) VALUES(1, 'Lutser', 'DB rookie', 110);
INSERT INTO Employee(id,name,zrank,salary) VALUES(1, 'Prutser', 'DB rookie', 90);
```

Note: since I used Postgres, there is a slight difference in syntax. Oracle does have domains, so the 'trick' to implement IC1 as a domain constraint is still valid.

Result:

```
CREATE DOMAIN
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "employee_pkey" for table "employee"
CREATE TABLE
ERROR:  value for domain dbarank violates check constraint "dbarank_check"
ERROR:  new row for relation "employee" violates check constraint "ic4"
INSERT 0 1
```

UPDATE: fixed the NOT(AND/OR) stuff, making the constraints exclusive.

Comment: `IC2`, `IC3` and `IC4`, as they're currently defined, prevent *any* rows from being inserted into this table.

Comment: I see, the OP had a difficulty with AND/OR, too. Didnot think it would be *that* trivial... I'll see if I can fix it.

Comment: The point of the assignment was to create constraints, the errors that come from those constraints are intended. We're analyzing where they came from and why. I greatly appreciate your help and assistance with the logic.

Comment: IMHO, the underlying problem is that there is an *implicit* AND involved: **all** the constraints for the table should be satisfied. The domain-constraint is something to remember. It can save you a lot of typing/work if a particular domain occurs more than once in a schema.